# SQL plus decrement value on trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a database in SQL Plus. I have a total of 3 tables: `Customer`, `Books` and `Borrowed_Book`.

The `Book` table has a `Stock` column where you write how many books are left.

1. Is there a way to update the `Stock` column of the `Book` table when I add an entry in the `Borrowed_Book` to decrement the stock by 1?
2. Furthermore, is there a way to increment back that book when the expiration date from the `Borrowed_Book` is reached?

Can this be done in SQL plus or does it have to have another code in another language to handle such things?

Comment: you need to use a trigger

Comment: The problem with your database design is that your `Book` table has a `Stock` column. Instead of using an explicit column, try to derive the number of left books from the other data.

Comment: Hi, just a note on your question. SQL Plus is just an Oracle client. A program developed and used to input/output data to a database in this case Oracle. So when you say "I am trying to create a database in SQL Plus" it is wrong you should say "I am trying to create a database in Oracle **using** SQL Plus" :)

Comment: I'm sorry Jorge, I'm still new to sql.